# jQuery validation inValidhandler called twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having a problem with the jquery validation plugin and the invalidHandler. The handler is being called twice? First time for the locally validated fields, and the second time is when all my remote ajax validation has finished.

I guess that this happens because the locally validated fields is returning false before the remote ones. Is it possible to fix this?

```
    $("#create users").validate(
        {
            debug: true,
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.closest('div').next().next());
            },
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) { // Called twice
                $("#validation-dialog").dialog('close');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $("#validation-dialog").dialog('close');
                $("#create-accounts-dialog").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        GetString("Cancel"): function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        GetString("Ok"): function() {
                            $(".modal-load").show();
                            $(".ui-icon-info").hide();
                            $(".modal-text").hide();
                            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").hide();
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    $.validator.addMethod("required", $.validator.methods.required, GetString("validationRequired"));
    $.validator.addMethod("email", $.validator.methods.email, GetString("validationRequired"));
    $.validator.addMethod("remote", $.validator.methods.remote,GetString("validationDouble"));
    $.validator.addClassRules("uEmail", { required: true, email: true, remote: "/CheckDouble/@Model.Id" });
```

Thanks,

James Ford

Comment: Can you show your HTML and construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue ('invalidHandler' is also called twice). Did you find out how to solve this ?

Comment: I have this error as well